# Merge line in csv file python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, merge

I have this in csv file:

```
Titre,a,b,c,d,e 
01,jean,paul,, 
01,,,jack,
02,jeanne,jack,,
02,,,jean
```

and i want :

```
Titre,a,b,c,d,e 
01,jean,paul,jack, 
02,jeanne,jack,,jean
```

can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, a good approach is to read the csv file and iterate through the rows using Python's CSV module.

CSV will create an iterator that will let you loop through your file like this:

```
import csv
with open('your filename.csv', 'r') as infile:
  reader = csv.reader(infile)
  for line in reader:
    for value in line:
      # Do your thing
```

You're going to need to construct a new data set that has different properties. The requirements you described:

1. Ignore any empty cells
2. Any time you encounter a row that has a new index number, add a new row to your new data set
3. Any time you encounter a row that has an index number you've seen before, add it to the row that you already created (except for that index number value itself)

I'm not writing that part of the code for you because you need to learn and grow. It's a good task for a beginner.

Once you've constructed that data set, it will look like this:

```
example_processed_data = [["Titre","a","b","c","d","e"],
    ["01","jean","paul","jack"],
    ["02","jeanne","jack","","jean"]]
```

You can then create a CSV writer, and create your outfile by iterating over that data, similarly to how you iterated over the infile:

```
with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
  writer = csv.writer(outfile)
  for line in example_processed_data:
    writer.writerow(line)
print("Done! Wrote", len(example_processed_data), "lines to outfile.csv.")
```

Comment: Read or iteration a csv file is not a problem, but my question is how to merge line

Comment: There is no single command (that I know of) that's going to merge your data in the exact way you've requested. The easiest way is just to get comfortable processing text in Python. We could write the function for you, but what will truly benefit you is to take a stab at it yourself. If your outfile doesn't look the way you want it to, then you can tweak it until it does, and if that doesn't work then you'll at least have something to show us. Good luck!